# Enable cancellation of openmp threads from inside program

Tags: c++, openmp, cancellation

According to the OpenMP specification, `OMP_CANCELLATION` must be set to true in order for statements like `#pragma omp cancel` to have any effect. I need the cancellation functionality to be enabled for my program to work properly (a GUI abort button that triggers the cancellation, if it matters).

I tried to set `OMP_CANCELLATION` from within the program with

```
setenv("OMP_CANCELLATION", "true", 1);
```

as the first line of the program, but this statement does not have any effect. If I manually `export OMP_CANCELLATION=true` from a shell outside before running the program, the cancellation works properly.

Is it possible to enable cancellation from within the program without requiring this environment variable to be set externally?

Comment: Maybe the value is queried even before `main()` runs? There is a thread [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/700267) that at least suggests that this may not be possible (albeit it is about FORTRAN).

Comment: It may be worth asking your question on the OpenMP ARB's forum http://forum.openmp.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=3 that way there is a chance that people involved with the standard notice this omission...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not possible to enable cancellation once the program starts (as per Zulan's answer), I managed to find a workaround:

```
char *hasCancel = getenv("OMP_CANCELLATION");
if (hasCancel == nullptr) {
    printf("Bootstrapping...");
    setenv("OMP_CANCELLATION", "true", 1);
    // Restart the program here
    int output = execvp(argv[0], argv);
    // Execution should not continue past here
    printf("Bootstrapping failed with code %d\n",output);
    exit(1);
} else {
    puts("Bootstrapping complete");
}
```

I set the variable in the program and then use an exec call to restart the process. The restarted process will have `OMP_CANCELLATION` properly set before it starts.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as per the [standard (Chapter 4)](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf):

> Modifications to the environment variables after the program has started, even if modified by the program itself, are ignored by the OpenMP implementation. However, the settings of some of the ICVs can be modified during the execution of the OpenMP program by the use of the appropriate directive clauses or OpenMP API
>   routines.

No such way to modify the value of *cancel-var* is specified (2.3.3).

You can sort out that issue by writing a wrapper program/script.

Some implementations could provide ways to modify the value regardless of what the standard says. But relying on that wouldn't be portable.